# Как перенаправить по адресу?

Tags: javascript

Помогите, пожалуйста, понять, почему мой код не перенаправляет по определенной ссылке.

На странице http://myhost.ru/brands/ находится примерно такой скрипт (привожу часть)

```
console.log(hostnameStr);   // 'http://myhost.ru'

    console.log(pathStr);   // '/brands'

    console.log(brandStr); // '/BlackBerry'

    alert(hostnameStr + pathStr + brandStr);

    document.location.href = hostnameStr + pathStr + brandStr;
```

До этого кода, я определяю переменные `hostnameStr`, `pathStr`, `brandStr`.
Затем, как видите, вывожу их в консоль и в модальное окно. При этом адрес показывается верный.

Но последняя строка перенаправляет примерно по такому адресу

```
http://myhost.ru/myhost.ru/brands/BlackBerry
```

По моей задумке перенаправление должно происходить по такому адресу

```
http://myhost.ru/brands/BlackBerry
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[document.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.location) , [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location)

из этого следует:

```
document.location=''+hostnameStr + pathStr + brandStr;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/yDELf/

а учитывая

> document.location was originally a read-only property, although Gecko browsers allow you to assign to it as well. For cross-browser safety, use window.location instead.

будет лучше

```
 window.location=''+hostnameStr + pathStr + brandStr;
```

Answer (score 0):

Перенаправляйте без хоста:

```
document.location.href = pathStr + brandStr;
```

Comment: это да. но хотелось бы причину понять. вопрос в этом был